# How to merge Git logs together?

Tags: git

If I have a Git branch that I want to merge into my master and I want the log history of that branch to be merged into the master's log history, should I be doing:

```
git checkout master
git merge <branch> --no-ff
```

or:

```
git checkout master
git merge <branch> --ff
```

or something else entirely?  The Git documentation isn't very clear (to me, at least) on this point.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a git hub? (E.g github/bitbucket/stash). If so I would recommend doing merges to master via a pull request instead of locally merging.

Comment: I'm using Bitbucket since it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both types of merges will maintain history. The difference is that `--no-ff` will always create an explicit merge commit, so there will be an entry in the logs and graphical tools like `gitk` will show that a branch and merge occurred. `--ff` will do a *fast-forward merge*, so there won't be an explicit merge commit made (unless the branch is not a direct descendant of the master branch).

Comment: @Robert: You should see all the commits in the log. If it was a fast-forward merge, though, there won't be a commit for the merge action itself.

Answer (score 0):

The git log will persist with either of these commands, as when you merge you are essentially squishing all your commits into the other branch. Fast forwarding is generally used when the branch you are merging into has had no commits since you made your changes, so instead of an extra merge commit being added, the changes are just added to your branch, 'fast forwarding' that branch to the latest commit you made.

Here is a nice explanation if the docs didn't help
http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge.html